# interface method that does not make sense for all implementing classes

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns, interface

So I work in this nice project that uses Spring and injects interfaces everywhere. The problem is: in one of my implementers, I have this method that just make sense in that specific implementation. How should I implement this method in the other classes?
Ex:

```
 public interface A {
           public String methodThatMakesSenseOnlyToImplementationA();
       }
```

Now the implementing classes:

```
 public class ImplementingInterfaceA implements A {
            public String methodThatMakesSenseOnlyToImplementationA() {
                 //many many crazy things here
            }
 }
```

For this class, I have to implement the method, but returning empty String looks dirty.

```
public class Nothing implements A {
        public String methodThatMakesSenseOnlyToImplementationA() {
             // this implementation will never use the method methodThatMakesSenseOnlyToImplementationA
        }
    }
```

How to solve this issue in a  nice way?

Comment: Split your interface, have a common one, and one just for Implementation A

Comment: how is the method used? does the caller know that the object that the method is being called on is of a type that has a useful implementation?

Comment: Why is the `Nothing` class implementing interface `A` if it doesn't need to implement the `methodThatMakesSenseOnlyToImplementationA()` method?

Comment: Hi @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner. The interface has other methods that need to be implemented. This specific method represents an operation that is particular to a specific implementation. It needs to be on the interface because on spring we declare the fields using the interface, not a specific implementation.

Comment: Hi @MaartenWinkels, please read the comment above. The method has to be called through the interface because the field is injected using Spring and thus we declare them as of Interface Type and not of a specific implementation

Comment: @felixthecar Just declare a default method in the interface, that returns an empty String. If not on java 8, use an abstract class with default method implementations and make your class extend it. If you can't extend from this class (maybe because you're already extending from another class), then split your interface into two or more interfaces and make your classes implement only the ones that make sense. In this case, you can create an interface that extends from all these small interfaces, make your class also extend it and make Spring inject this interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` when there is no reasonable implementation and you know that the method is not getting called.

Comment: I like this solution because it is simple and it solves my problem elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing interface A for class `Nothing`. Extend class `ImplementingInterfaceA` . It will inherit the already implemented method.

Or if you are using java 8, use default method in your interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the extra-methods in another `interface`- say `B`- so you'll have two interfaces `A` and `B`.

- **Method 1**

  ```
  public interface B {
      //here are the methods that make some sense for all the classes
  }
  ```

  Interfaces can extend interfaces:

  ```
  public interface A extends B {
      public String methodThatMakesSenseOnlyToImplementationA();
  }
  ```

  The classes may implement different interfaces:

  ```
  public class ImplementingInterfaceA implements A {
      . . .
  }

  public class Nothing implements B {
      . . .
  }
  ```
- **Method 2**

  You can have completely separated interfaces:

  ```
  public interface B {
      //here are the methods that make some sense for all the classes
  }

  public interface A {
      public String methodThatMakesSenseOnlyToImplementationA();
  }
  ```

  The classes are allowed to implement one or more interfaces:

  ```
  public class ImplementingInterfaceA implements A, B {
      . . .
  }

  public class Nothing implements B {
      . . .
  }
  ```